# How to make the readonly textfield noneditable by Firebug?

Tags: html, struts2, struts, firebug

We have a textfield with the `readonly` attribute set, e.g.,

```
<s:textfield id="xyz" name="test" value="xyz" readonly="true" />
```

While inspecting through Firebug the value of the field can be edited and the edited value is submitted.

How do I prevent `readonly` fields from being edited through Firebug?

Comment: @SebastianZartner  The formatting was missing; please feel free to edit/examine questions that appear to be missing information, particularly HTML-ish info.

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

Validation needs to be handled on the back end, regardless of any client-side validation/properties you've set. Clients can *always* send requests you don't expect, whether through malice or simple twiddling. If something shouldn't be editable then the back end needs to ensure it isn't.